# How to change background image of the css block using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<style type="text/css">
            .RadWindow .rwWindowContent .radalert
            {
                background-image:url("images/InfoImg.png"); 
            }
        </style>
```

The above code in  css file ,i want change   the background image of the above css file,
when user call the Jquery costume function,I want to Change the background image of rad alert.

Comment: On a related note, three class selectors ?
That could slow down page rendering.

Answer (score 4):

Use two classes :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .RadWindow .rwWindowContent .radalert {
         background-image:url("images/InfoImg.png"); 
    }
    .RadWindow.newbg .rwWindowContent .radalert {
         background-image:url("images/other_image.png"); 
    }
</style>
```

JS:

```
$('.RadWindow').addClass('newbg');    // adds the new background
$('.RadWindow').removeClass('newbg'); // removes the new background
$('.RadWindow').toggleClass('newbg'); // toggles the new background
```

Comment: great answer, you should really mention jQuery's [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) ability

Answer (score 2):

let suppose you have to change the url of the image to "images/InfoImg2.png"
you can use the code option 1-

jQuery -

```
var newUrl = "images/InfoImg2.png";
$(".radalert").css({
    backgroundImage : 'url("'+newUrl+'")'
});
```

**OR**

CSS -

```
RadWindow .rwWindowContent .radalert2{
  background-image:url("images/InfoImg2.png"); 
}
```

jQuery -

```
$(".radalert").addClass("radalert2");
```

Comment: these are all good answers, though i have to go with the 2 class idead myself, as best suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple old fashioned method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.RadWindow .rwWindowContent .radalert')
    .css('background-image', "url('images/InfoImg.png')");
})
```

**OR**

as per comment request, you could make use of jQuery's [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method. To make best advantage, simple set 2 alternating background classes in css. Assign one to your element on load (write it in the HTML) and simply have the other one ready. Then, on an "action", use toggleClass to alternate the two classes!

## Working Example

How it works is simple. First set up your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-type-01 {
        background-image: url("some url");
    }
    .bg-type-02 {
        background-image: url("another url");
    }
</style>
```

Then apply your first class to your element:

```
<div class="radalert bg-type-01"> ... </div>
```

Finally, write the very simple JS with jQuery!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("something").on("click", function(e) {
            $(".radalert").toggleClass("bg-type-01 bg-type-02");
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: all good answers, but i gota point out, having 2 classes gives the editor the "toggle" ability without a bunch of extra code

Comment: The selector is not the same as the OP's one : there should be space between classes (ancestor selector) instead of commas (other selector)...

Comment: I thought that they are diff classes,sorry for that,I have edited those,Thanx

Comment: @Gautam3164 ok right...

Comment: Can you consider the toggleClass also..??

Comment: @Gautam3164 gave ya a litle edit boost and fiddle! ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.RadWindow .rwWindowContent .radalert').css('background-image', 'images/new.png')
```

Comment: lol, you're late to the party, but here's a point anyway